# React/Redux: Pass data to Sibling Component after API Call

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga

I am new to React and Redux Saga.

I am having two siblings components. In one component, in "componentDidMount", I am calling one API using redux-saga.  and also able to update the view based on that response.

Now I want the same data in my other component. For now, I am dispatching the same action to get the data but that is making the API call again which is expected.

So I want to find the correct solution for this. So that there will be only one call and if the data is present then I can use the same in the second call.

Comment: Seriously, do not use Redux Saga if you are just starting out with React. Just stick with plain Redux, then try out Redux Thunk if you need async actions (although I almost never do and there are better ways to deal with side effects and then if that is not enough, then try Redux Saga.

Answer (score 1):

Before you call the API set a parameter in the redux store that will mark that API is being called (its initial value is false).

Both components will test this parameter and call the the API only if it is false.